# Loop animation n number of times in canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Looking to be able to loop through a given animation a specific number of times using HTML5 Canvas and Javascript, no jQueryor any other additional libraries?
Would be along the lines of a bonus game feature, where when once initiated it would loop animation a given number of times, until bonus game feature ends.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to look into setInterval, setTimeout and requestAnimationFrame.  Here's a starting point:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations

Comment: Current using setInterval, setTimeout and requestAnimationFrame. Will not allow me to loop through the a predefined number of times. That is where the problem is!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found my answer, it was within my code!